# Accessible Tiles

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm aiming for an accessible Website with tiles to group content. They are implemented as a styled div which has no other syntactical purpose than to group its content.

```
  <div class="tile">
    <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
    <a href="#messages">Messages</a>
    <a href="#documents">My Documents</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tile">
    <a href="#jobs">Jobs</a>
    <a href="#education">Education</a>
    <a href="#faq">FAQ</a>
  </div>

    .tile {
    background-color: white;
      border-width:   2px;
      border-radius:  4px;
      border-color:   transparent;
    }
```

I'd like to provide information for screen readers that its content belongs together. On the other hand I can't use global IDs (like with using the WAI ARIA group-role).

Is there any syntactical technique to tell my screenreader-users which rich-text contents belong together without the use of global IDs?

(Q1) Would `<section>` be a valid, understandable solution?

Kind Regards

EDIT: Added example; Added Question (Q1)

Comment: Please add more code detail to your question with more dummy content to a tile and perhaps an adjacent one.  It's unclear what your accessibility problem actually is.  Also, `<section>` has nothing to do with forms.

Comment: Hello Steve, I'll do so. But it is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct would be to make each of these a list - it adds some extra markup, but it is a nice way to group related concepts. Another option (you could use both of these together, if you wanted) is to use an invisible header. An h2, h3, or whatever the appropriate header level is for each of these blocks, with the css making it invisible (not via `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`, though; look up "accessible screen-reader text" for more details on this pattern.)

You could also use a `role=group` with an appropriate `aria-label` on each parent div, if you want, but I think the list and/or header semantics are more common.

Comment: Thank you very much, jack! It sounds reasonable and I'll try both of approaches. I just realised that it is possible to use role=group without global IDs. This changes a lot. :)